# Constructing SQL Select Query from the conditions in other table

Tags: sql-server

Help required for a SQL Server query.

`Users` table:

```
UserID      FirstName  LastName
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Sasasd     asdfhy
2           Sachnahi   Jhootey
3           csajd      mkjcy
4           Scsajd     aiuyay
5           csdcsajd   aiuyawe
```

Custom query table:

```
FieldOrigin|FieldID|FieldType|FieldCondition|FieldNumberValue|FieldTextValue
1          |2      |1        |2             |null            |s
1          |3      |1        |3             |null            |y
```

- FieldType: `1 = Text, 2 = Number`
- FieldCondition : `1 - Contains, 2 - Starts with, 3 - Ends with, 4 - Equals`

I need help in writing query to get UserID's from the `Users` table, which abide to the conditions in the custom query table.

Query: find the user ids from `Users` whose names start with `s` and ends with `y`

I tried writing this query but this isn't working:

```
SELECT U.UserID 
FROM CUSTOM_TABLE C, Users U
WHERE C.FieldOrigin = 1
  AND (CASE C.FieldID
          WHEN 2 
             THEN 
                (CASE 
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 1 AND U.FirstName LIKE '%' + C.FieldTextValue +'%'  
                       THEN 1
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 2 AND U.FirstName  LIKE C.FieldTextValue +'%' 
                       THEN 1
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 3 AND U.FirstName LIKE '%' + C.FieldTextValue 
                       THEN 1
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 4 AND U.FirstName = C.FieldTextValue 
                       THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END)
          WHEN 3 
             THEN 
                (CASE 
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 1 AND U.LastName LIKE '%' + C.FieldTextValue +'%' 
                       THEN 1
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 2 AND U.LastName LIKE C.FieldTextValue +'%' 
                       THEN 1
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 3 AND U.LastName LIKE '%' + C.FieldTextValue 
                       THEN 1
                    WHEN C.FieldCondition = 4 AND U.LastName = C.FieldTextValue 
                       THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END)
            ELSE 0
    END) = 1
GROUP BY 
    U.UserID
```

This returns `1,2,3,4` but the correct answer is `1,2,4`

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa9a391b2392cf4b60f49baf06995d36)

Comment: So your problem seems to be that you get an OR between the conditions when you want an AND? firstname starts with 's' AND lastname ends with 'y'

Comment: yes, it should satisfy both conditions

Comment: You should probably be working with dynamic sql here so that you build a query using the content of the `CUSTOM_TABLE` and then execute that query. I don't think you can do this directly as in your current approach.

Comment: I would like to have this query as Stored Procedure, as you see in  [Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa9a391b2392cf4b60f49baf06995d36) I'm using JSON format to set conditions, any help on writing Dynamic query which would solve my problem?

Comment: Well a stored procedure was what I had in mind so I don't disagree.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @query varchar(1000)
declare @i int = 0
Set @query  = 'SELECT U.UserID from  Users U where ' 
select  @query  = @query + case @i when 0 THEN '' ELSE ' AND ' END +
CASE C.FieldID
WHEN 2 THEN 
    (CASE 
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 1 THEN 'U.FirstName LIKE ''%' + C.FieldTextValue +'%'''
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 2 THEN 'U.FirstName LIKE ''' + C.FieldTextValue +'%'''
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 3 THEN 'U.FirstName LIKE ''%' + C.FieldTextValue +''''
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 4 THEN 'U.FirstName =''' + C.FieldTextValue +''''
        ELSE ''
    END)
WHEN 3 THEN 
    (CASE 
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 1 THEN 'U.LastName LIKE ''%' + C.FieldTextValue +'%'''
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 2 THEN 'U.LastName LIKE ''' + C.FieldTextValue +'%'''
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 3 THEN 'U.LastName LIKE ''%' + C.FieldTextValue +''''
        WHEN C.FieldCondition = 4 THEN 'U.LastName =''' + C.FieldTextValue +''''
        ELSE ''
    END)
ELSE ''
END, @i=@i+(
              CASE WHEN (C.FieldID = 2 OR C.FieldID = 3) AND 
                  (C.FieldCondition = 1 OR C.FieldCondition = 2 OR C.FieldCondition = 3 OR C.FieldCondition = 4) THEN 1
              ELSE 0 END
            )
from CUSTOM_TABLE C where C.FieldOrigin = 1

exec  (@query)
```

It is not elegant solution but it works

Comment: Yes, this works, I didn't understand this part @i=@i+1

Comment: I did some modification for @i=@i+1. It indicates where it is needed to pass first operator 'AND' in condition.

Comment: Look line    case @i when 0 THEN '' ELSE ' AND '